# In Javascript: How to remove a "form-group has-success" or "form-group has-error" class from an element and reset to default?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reset the ag,usrnm,pswd,cnfrm elements to remove (when I click a reset button that triggers the reset function) "form-group has-success" or "form-group has-error" classes that were added earlier. I have tried several things as seen before and none of them work.

I also have a 2nd issue with a div on the bottom of the main screen with errors that I am trying to clear and it is not working with reseting the innerHTML to "".

So far only the reseting of the inputs on the form works.

```
<script>
```

...

```
  function resetfunc(){
     document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
     document.getElementById("ag").className.clear;
     document.getElementById("usrnm").removeClass('has-error');
     document.getElementById("pswrd").className.clear;
     document.getElementById("cnfrm").className.clear;
     return false;
}
```

-----edit here. reposted more code from here down-----

```
 <style type="text/css">
     .container {
      width: 500px;
      clear:both;
     }
      .container input{
        width:100%;
        clear:both;
      }
      .buttons{
        text-align:center;
      }

      #output{
        text-align:center;
        visibility: hidden;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="return valfunc()" onreset="return resetfunc()" ;>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="usrnm">
          <label class="control-label">Username: </label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username">
        </div>
        <div id="pswrd">
          <label class="control-label">Password: </label>
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>
        <div id="cnfrm">
          <label class="control-label">Confirm: </label>
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm">
        </div>
        <div id="ag">
          <label class="control-label">Age: </label>
          <input class="form-control" align:"right" type="text" name="age" id="age"> <br>
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onsubmit="valfunc();">
        <input type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-default" onreset="resetfunc()">
       </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="output">
      <ul> </ul>
    </div>


    <script>


    function valfunc() {

    document.getElementById("output").style.visibility = "visible";
    var username = 
      document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = 
      document.getElementById("password").value;
    var confirm = 
      document.getElementById("confirm").value;
    var age =
      document.getElementById("age").value;
    var myerror = "";
    var nouser = 0;

    var error = [];

    if (username.length==0)
    {
      nouser = 1;
      myerror += "<li> Username field has been left blank.";
      error[0] = 1;
    }

    if (password.length==0)
    {
      myerror += "<li> Password field has been left blank.";
      error[1] = 1;
    }

    if (confirm.length==0)
    {
      myerror += "<li> Confirm field has been left blank.";
      error[2] = 1;
    }

    if (age.length==0)
    {
      myerror += "<li> Age field has been left blank.";
      error[3] = 1;
    }

    if ((username.length <5) || (username.length > 15))
    {
      myerror += 
      "<li> Username should be between 5 and 15 characters long.";
      error[0] = 1;
    }

    if (password !== confirm) {
      myerror += 
      "<li> Password and Confirm input text box values should match.";
      error[1] = 1;
      error[2] = 1 ; 
    }

    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(username.match(letters)){
     }
     else if(nouser==1){
     }
     else {
      myerror += 
      "<li> Username can only have letters.";
      error[0] = 1;
     }

    if (age <= 0) {
      myerror += 
      "<li> Age should be a positive integer.";
      error[3] = 1;    
    } else {
      if ((age<18)||(age>110)){
      myerror += 
      "<li> Age should be between the values 18 and 110.";
      error[3] = 1;
      }
    }


    if (error[0]==1){
      document.getElementById("usrnm").className = "form-group has-error";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("usrnm").className = "form-group has-success";
    }

    if (error[1]==1){
      document.getElementById("pswrd").className = "form-group has-error";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("pswrd").className = "form-group has-success";
    }

    if (error[2]==1){
      document.getElementById("cnfrm").className = "form-group has-error";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("cnfrm").className = "form-group has-success";
    }

    if (error[3]==1){
      document.getElementById("ag").className = "form-group has-error";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("ag").className = "form-group has-success";
    }


    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myerror;

    if (myerror.length > 1) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Form values successfully validated.";
      document.getElementById("output").className = "alert alert-success";
      return true;
    }

    }

    function resetfunc(){
      document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("ag").className.clear;
      document.getElementById("usrnm").removeClass('has-error');
      document.getElementById("pswrd").className=""
      document.getElementById("cnfrm").className.clear;
      return false;
    }




    </script>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("pswrd").className="" instead of clear and it should be a function call not a property use

Comment: i tried that and no luck

Comment: paste your html as well

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0):

For remove classnames ,You should use `node.classList.remove('className')`:

```
function resetfunc(){
     document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
     document.getElementById("ag").classList.remove('classNameExample');
     document.getElementById("usrnm").classList.remove('has-error');
     document.getElementById("pswrd").classList.remove('classNameExample');
     document.getElementById("cnfrm").classList.remove('classNameExample');
     return false;
}
```

I rebuild your code:

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        let output = document.getElementById("output");
        let username = document.getElementById("username");
        let password = document.getElementById("password");
        let confirm = document.getElementById("confirm");
        let age = document.getElementById("age");
        let reset = document.getElementById('reset');
        let submit = document.getElementById('submit');
        let list = document.getElementById('list');


        let usernameContainer = document.getElementById("usrnm");
        let passwordContainer = document.getElementById("pswrd");
        let confirmContainer = document.getElementById("cnfrm");
        let ageContainer = document.getElementById('ag');

        reset.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
            resetfunc();
        })
        submit.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {

            valfunc(ev);
        })

        function valfunc(ev) {

            output.style.visibility = "visible";
            var usernameValue = username.value;
            var passwordValue = password.value;
            var confirmValue = confirm.value;
            var ageValue = age,
                value;
            var myerror = "";
            var nouser = 0;
            var error = [];
            let clearListItem = document.createElement('li');
            let docFrError = new DocumentFragment();
            // let  docFrError = new DocumentFragment();

            if (usernameValue.length == 0) {
                nouser = 1;
                let cloneLi = clearListItem.cloneNode();
                cloneLi.textContent = 'Username field has been left blank.'
                docFrError.append(cloneLi);
                error[0] = 1;
            } else if ((usernameValue.length < 5) || (usernameValue.length > 15)) {
                let cloneLi = clearListItem.cloneNode();
                cloneLi.textContent = 'Username should be between 5 and 15 characters long'
                docFrError.append(cloneLi);
                error[0] = 1;
            }


            if (passwordValue.length == 0) {
                let cloneLi = clearListItem.cloneNode();
                cloneLi.textContent = 'Password field has been left blank.'
                docFrError.append(cloneLi);
                error[1] = 1;
            }else if (passwordValue !== confirmValue) {
                let cloneLi = clearListItem.cloneNode();
                cloneLi.textContent = 'Password and Confirm input text box values should match'
                docFrError.append(cloneLi);
                error[1] = 1;
                error[2] = 1;
            }

            var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
            if (usernameValue.match(letters)) {} else if (nouser == 1) {} else {
                let cloneLi = clearListItem.cloneNode();
                cloneLi.textContent = 'Username can only have letters.'
                docFrError.append(cloneLi);
                error[0] = 1;
            }


            if (confirmValue.length == 0) {
                let cloneLi = clearListItem.cloneNode();
                cloneLi.textContent = 'Confirm field has been left blank.'
                docFrError.append(cloneLi);
                error[2] = 1;
            }

            if (ageValue.length == 0) {
                let cloneLi = clearListItem.cloneNode();
                cloneLi.textContent = 'Age field has been left blank.'
                docFrError.append(cloneLi);
                error[3] = 1;
            }else

            if (ageValue <= 0) {
                let cloneLi = clearListItem.cloneNode();
                cloneLi.textContent = 'Age should be a positive integer.'
                docFrError.append(cloneLi);
                error[3] = 1;
            } else 
                if ((ageValue < 18) || (ageValue > 110)) {
                      let cloneLi = clearListItem.cloneNode();
                cloneLi.textContent = 'Age should be between the values 18 and 110.'
                docFrError.append(cloneLi);
                error[3] = 1;                
            }

            if (error[0] == 1) {
                usernameContainer.classList.add("form-group", "has-error");
            } else {
                usernameContainer.classList.add("form-group", "has-success");
            }

            if (error[1] == 1) {
                passwordContainer.classList.add("form-group", "has-error");
            } else {
                passwordContainer.classList.add("form-group", "has-success");
            }

            if (error[2] == 1) {
                confirmContainer.classList.add("form-group", "has-error");
            } else {
                confirmContainer.classList.add("form-group", "has-success");
            }

            if (error[3] == 1) {
                ageContainer.classList.add("form-group", "has-error");
            } else {
                ageContainer.classList.add("form-group", "has-success");
            }

            

            if (docFrError.childNodes.length > 0) {
            list.append(docFrError);
                            ev.preventDefault();
            } else {
                let cloneLi = clearListItem.cloneNode();
                cloneLi.textContent = 'Form values successfully validated.'
                docFrError.append(cloneLi);
                output.classList.add("alert", " alert-success");
            list.append(docFrError);
                return true;
            }

        }

        function resetfunc() {
            list.innerHTML = "";
            ageContainer.classList.remove("form-group", "has-success", 'has-error');
            usernameContainer.classList.remove('has-error');
            passwordContainer.classList.remove("form-group", "has-success", 'has-error');
            confirmContainer.classList.remove("form-group", "has-success", 'has-error');
        }
    });
```

```html
  <form id="myForm">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="usrnm">
                <label class="control-label">Username: </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div id="pswrd">
                <label class="control-label">Password: </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <div id="cnfrm">
                <label class="control-label">Confirm: </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm">
            </div>
            <div id="ag">
                <label class="control-label">Age: </label>
                <input class="form-control" align: "right" type="text" name="age" id="age">
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-default">
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="output">
        <ul id="list"> </ul>
    </div>
```